# Convert a Vec<String> into an IIterable<HSTRING> using Rust and windows-rs

Tags: rust, windows-rs

I am using Rust and the [windows-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) crate to access the Windows API from Rust.

As input, I have an `Vec<String>` which I want to convert into an `IIterable<HSTRING>`.
According to [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/91#issuecomment-1441666146), it should be possible to use the `try_from` trait.

Here is what I've tried:

```
let hStringVector: Vec<HSTRING> = stringVector.iter().map(|c| HSTRING::from(c)).collect()?; 
let storeidsWin = IIterable::<HSTRING>::try_from(storeIdsWinRaw);
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `IIterable<HSTRING>: From<Vec<HSTRING>>` is not satisfied
   --> src\lib.rs:104:58
    |
104 |         let storeidsWin = IIterable::<HSTRING>::try_from(hStringVector);
    |                           ------------------------------ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Vec<HSTRING>>` is not implemented for `IIterable<HSTRING>`
    |                           |
    |                           required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = note: required for `Vec<HSTRING>` to implement `Into<IIterable<HSTRING>>`
    = note: required for `IIterable<HSTRING>` to implement `TryFrom<Vec<HSTRING>>`
```

Unfortunately I am new to Rust and don't know what this error wants to tell me (and how to fix it).

Comment: I think you might need to check impls of `IIterable` to see how can it convert from `Vec<T>`. [Code](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/a98ae0578b787e67546303186b46494f0c0a7a46/crates/tools/riddle/src/rust/extensions/impl/Foundation/Collections/Iterable.rs#L86C1-L86C1) shows the restriction of `T`. No idea whether `HSTRING` has these traits.